# Issues with deploying a project in SSAS: "Cannot deploy metadata"

Tags: sqlite, ssas, olap, cubes, analytical

I'm really-really new to working with SSAS, so please excuse me in advance.
I have a data base file called "UZB", consisting of 1 table, which I created with sqlite, and store locally on my PC. It's not corrupted or anything, I was viewing it just fine via sqlite viewer.

I use Visual Studio 2019,I installed SSAS via extensions.

I've downloaded a sqlite ODBC driver and successfully added my sqlite DB in SSAS Data connections:
[screenshot #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AE8Ws.png)

I even executed a couple of SQL queries to the table within SSAS somehow, and it worked fine.

But when i try to deploy a project, both tabular or multidimensional, I get a "Cannot deploy metadata" error.  I also don't see my connection in "Existing connections" (Tabular Model Explorer ->Data sources) which is weird to me, given that i clearly see that a connection exists in  Data connections window as shown in the screenshot.

I've seen a similar thread, pretty much the only advice was to go to Solution Explorer -> Project -> Properties and rename your server name to the actual name, instead of "localhost". I'm a little bit baffled about this part, as I don't run a server per se, I just use my local PC all the way, but still I've noticed that in the very same Data connections window under "Servers" it says "E-MaxPC" so I've used this name, didn't help:
[screenshot 2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XD2SP.png

Any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

P.S. I've googled this problem, saw some other stackoverflow threads, but i didn't help me.